# How to combine two artifacts from two different pipelines in Azure DevOps using yaml?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am generating two different artifacts from two different pipelines and I need to combine both html reports from both pipelines and create common HTML report.

```
Pipeline_1 - test1.html
Pipeline_2 - test2.html
```

I want to create new pipeline and download both test1.html and test2.html files from both pipelines and generate common html file from both test1.html and test2.html files using yaml in Azure DevOps.

```
Pipeline_3 - (test1.html -> test2.html) = test3.html
```

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can consume both pipelines artifacts with the [resources pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#resources), for example:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyAppA
    source: MyCIPipelineA
  - pipeline: MyAppB
    source: MyCIPipelineB
```